# How to get the source codes of Tour of Heroes app and tutorial for Angular version 13?

Tags: angular, angular-tour-of-heroes

How to get the source codes of Tour of Heroes app and tutorial for Angular version 13?

https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip get the source codes of Tour of Heroes app and tutorial for Angular version 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://v13.angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt6/toh-pt6.zip

in the bottom left corner of the angular website you can change the version